# Incoming email settings in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have email id for which incoming email is configured for a document library in site collection. We have 2000 sharepoint sites. How to check which document library is configured with particular email ID for incoming email ?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell command below to loop the web application and use CanReceieveEmail and EmailAlias parameter to check the email alias.

```
$SPwebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sp"
foreach ($SPsite in $SPwebApp.Sites)
{ 
foreach($SPweb in $SPsite.AllWebs)
{
    foreach ($SPList in $SPweb.Lists)
    {
        if ( ($splist.CanReceiveEmail) -and ($SPlist.EmailAlias -eq "emailname") )
        {
            WRITE-HOST "E-Mail: " $SPList.EmailAlias "@contoso.com , List: " $SPlist.Title ", Web: " $SPweb.Url
        }
    }
}
}
```